# Move SAP package to top level

Tags: abap

We have a subpackage thet we want to move up to the top level, so that it doesn't have any superpackage anymore.

The 'change' dialog for superpackage does not allow an empty value:
[image: Error when entering blank package name]

Is there another way to do this, or does the package need to be deleted and recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a UI function to remove that assignment. However, you could try to do this programmatically: use `CL_PACKAGE_FACTORY` to load the package (you'll get an instance of `IF_PACKAGE`), then call `SET_SUPER_PACKAGE_NAME`. Haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: I did a quick test, and it fails with `Exception condition "SUPER_OBJECT_INVALID" triggered` because the package is not a main package yet. I couldn't find a way to make it a main package through `IF_PACKAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's stored in table TDEVC field PARENTCL. So you can try (at your own risk) to edit the record and remove superpackage from there.